# What does it mean, "had a quick spin on someone"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Fletcher says to Ray about what Dave did to Michael for not accepting his hand at a party :

> Fletcher: Turns out Dave had gone after one of Mickey's lords, did a
>   proper tabloid job on him. It would appear that His Lordship **had had a
>   quick spin on one of his attractive young footmen**. After the splash,
>   shares crashed, job went, wife followed, and even his kids disowned
>   him. Well, that Dave can't half be a cunt.

What does it mean, "had a quick spin on someone"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take a car for a quick spin is to take it for a brief drive (or ride, which can have sexual connotations); it seems that the lord mentioned had had a brief homosexual/gay affair with one of his servants ('attractive' is a clue to this), and that Dave (a tabloid newspaper journalist?) had exposed this fact in a story in his newspaper. 'Cunt' is often used in British slang (it is very offensive) to mean (of men) treacherous, disloyal, spiteful, cruel, selfish, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard phrase, but we can guess from the context (and so can you)

A "footman" is a junior servant. And "His Lordship" did something with that "attractive" footman that:

1. Would cause a bit of a scandal, so it could be reported (splashed) in the "tabloid" newspapers.
2. Would cause his wife to leave him.
3. Might cause his kids to disown him.

It should be easily understood.